# Python 2.7 - pandas.read_table - how to import quadruple-pipe-separated fields from flat file

Tags: python, pandas, separator

I am a decent SAS programmer, but I am quite new in Python. Now, I have been given Twitter feeds, each saved into **very large** flat files, with headers in row #1 and a data structure like the below:

```
CREATED_AT||||ID||||TEXT||||IN_REPLY_TO_USER_ID||||NAME||||SCREEN_NAME||||DESCRIPTION||||FOLLOWERS_COUNT||||TIME_ZONE||||QUOTE_COUNT||||REPLY_COUNT||||RETWEET_COUNT||||FAVORITE_COUNT

Tue Nov 14 12:33:00 +0000 2017||||930413253766791168||||ICYMI: Football clubs join the craft beer revolution! A good read|||| ||||BAB||||BABBrewers||||Monthly homebrew meet-up at 1000 Trades, Jewellery Quarter. First Tuesday of the month. All welcome, even if you've never brewed before.||||95|||| ||||0||||0||||0||||0
Tue Nov 14 12:34:00 +0000 2017||||930413253766821456||||I'm up for it|||| ||||Misty||||MistyGrl||||You CAN DO it!||||45|||| ||||0||||0||||0||||0
```

I guess it's like that because any sort of characters can be found in a Twitter feed, but a quadruple pipe is unlikely enough.

I know some people use JSON for that, but I've got these files as such: lots of them. I could use SAS to easily transform these files, but I prefer to "go pythonic", this time.

Now, I cannot seem to find a way to make Python (2.7) understand that the quadruple pipe is the actual separator. The output from the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('C:/Users/myname.mysurname/Desktop/my_twitter_flow_1.txt') as theInFile:
    inTbl = pd.read_table(theInFile, engine='python', sep='||||', header=1)
    print inTbl.head()
```

seem to suggest that Python does not see the distinct fields as distinct but, simply, brings in each of the first 5 rows, up to the line feed character, ignoring the |||| separator.

Basically, I am getting an output like the one I wrote above to show you the data structure.

Any hints?

Comment: Aside: if you're quite new in Python, you should probably not start out with an outdated version like 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using just the data in your question:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('rio.txt', sep='\|{4}', skip_blank_lines=True, engine='python')
>>> df
                       CREATED_AT                  ID  \
0  Tue Nov 14 12:33:00 +0000 2017  930413253766791168   
1  Tue Nov 14 12:34:00 +0000 2017  930413253766821456   

                                                TEXT IN_REPLY_TO_USER_ID  \
0  ICYMI: Football clubs join the craft beer revo...                       
1                                      I'm up for it                       

    NAME SCREEN_NAME                                        DESCRIPTION  \
0    BAB  BABBrewers  Monthly homebrew meet-up at 1000 Trades, Jewel...   
1  Misty    MistyGrl                                     You CAN DO it!   

   FOLLOWERS_COUNT TIME_ZONE  QUOTE_COUNT  REPLY_COUNT  RETWEET_COUNT  \
0               95                      0            0              0   
1               45                      0            0              0   

   FAVORITE_COUNT  
0               0  
1               0
```

Notice the `sep` parameter. When it's more than one character long and not equal to '\s+' it's interpreted as a regular expression. But the '|' character has special meaning in a regex, hence it must be escaped, using the '\' character. I could simply have written `sep='\|\|\|\|'`; however, I've used an abbreviation.

Comment: Very neat answer ! +1

Comment: @MaxU: Thanks very much!

Comment: Thank you, @BillBell...! :-)

Comment: @RioPugliese: You're very welcome. If it does what you wanted you can mark the answer accepted.